# Here is my C function prog it takes input from user loop with if condition with use of break statement

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, numbers, break

Here is a C function program. It looks to take input from user, loop thru with `if` condition and use of a `break` statement:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, Number, count = 0;

  printf("\n Please Enter any number to Check for Prime \n");

  scanf("%d", &Number);

  for (i = 2; i <= Number/2; i++) {
    if(Number == 0) {
      count++;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(count == 0 && Number != 1 ) {
    printf("\n %d is a Prime Number", Number);
  } else {
    printf("\n %d is Not a Prime Number", Number);
  }

  getch();

  return 0;
}
```

I can't understand how this program is working, can someone kindly explain how this part works?

```
  for (i = 2; i <= Number/2; i++) {
    if(Number == 0) {
      count++;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `if (Number == 0)` I think you are missing something there. Maybe `if (Number % i == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it line by line:

```
for (i = 2; i <= Number/2; i++)
```

Start a `for` loop, and iterate till we reach the value `Number / 2`. So if `Number = 12`, `i` will increment till it is equal to half of that value, in this case `6`.

```
 if(Number == 0) {
    count++;
    break; 
 }
```

If `Number` is zero, increment(add 1) `count` variable and stop the loop. Since you are checking for prime numbers this line is incorrect. It should be `if (Number % i == 0)` instead. `%` is the modulus operator, it will give you the remainder of a division. For e.g `12 % 6` is 0, because there is no remainder. So, `count` is incremented if there is a number which can divide `Number` and the remainder is `0`, meaning `Number` is not prime.

```
if(count == 0 && Number != 1 )
```

Here, we check if `count` is `0` AND `Number` is not 1. If both these conditions are true, then we have found a prime number.